# Unable to cast integer to string for exception with variable message

Tags: c++, string, templates

I'm in the process of implementing a Red-Black tree in C++, and I am currently writing code for my insertion method. Everything functions as it should, but for some reason, I can't get this tree_exception to throw an error with a variable message. My code uses generics, and the following works for all types of keys except for integer keys. Instead of the value, the program just prints out a bunch of empty space. Does anyone know how I could get this code to work for all types of input?

```
void insert(const K &key, const V &value) {
        iterator e = end();
        if(find(key) == end()) {
            insert(e, std::pair<K, V>(key, value));
        } else {
            throw tree_exception("Attempt to insert duplicate key '" + std::string(""+key) + "'.");
        }
    }
```

EDIT: For simplicity's sake, let's assume that a key can only be a character, an integer, or a string.

Comment: What does `std::string(""+key)` mean?

Comment: @Gupta -- That means "too much Java".

Comment: *how I could get this code to work for all types of input?* -- Even keys that are not integer?  What about keys that are types that are comparable, but `std::string` cannot handle?  It can be done, but need confirmation before posting any sort of answer.

Comment: Note that a Red-Black tree probably shouldn't insert all new elements at the end, but in order.

Comment: @BenVoigt As I mentioned in my post, my code works. The only problem I have is this exception.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, that means "desperation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good job for `std::ostringstream`, let it handle converting different input types to `std::string` for you:

```
insert(const K &key, const V &value) {
    iterator e = end();
    if(find(key) == e) {
        insert(e, std::make_pair(key, value));
    } else {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Attempt to insert duplicate key '" << key << "'.";
        throw tree_exception(oss.str());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert a numeric value to a string, instead of

```
std::string(""+key)
```

You want

```
std::to_string(key)
```

For a more flexible solution, you can use stringstream

Comment: As far as I know that won't work if the key is already a string.

Comment: We need the OP to confirm if all they want are integer keys.  In the question, the OP stated that it should be "all types of input".

Comment: @RetiredNinja: `template<typename T> std::string really_to_string(const T& inp) { return std::to_string(inp); }  template<> std::string really_to_string<std::string>(const std::string& inp) { return inp; }`  Or standards committee should just get around to adding a `std::to_string(std::string)` overload/specialization that returns its parameter as above.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Keys can be characters, integers, strings, etc. Anything that a generic type in C++ can support.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Correct, I couldn't just use 'to_string'.

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears what if the key is a user-defined type then?

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears -- This really should be moved to the main comment section.  But what if the user has a "big integer" class, and has the big Integer as keys.  The keys are also comparable, and `std::string` or `to_string` knows nothing about that type.  There are ways to solve your problem, but just letting you know about this issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Why wouldn't `to_string` know about the big integer type?  One is allowed to add overloads and specializations to namespace std so long as they depend on a user-defined type.  The problem is with `to_string(std::string)` which doesn't exist and can't be added since it only depends on a standard library type.  Almost certainly a specialization of `std::less` is already needed for any type intended for use as a key.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For simplicity's sake, let's assume that a key can only be an integer, character, or a string.

Comment: `template<typename T> std::string really_to_string(const T& inp) { if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) { return inp; } else { return std::to_string(inp); } }`